# OData Model Display Property from first line

Tags: odata, sapui5

I'm using an OData Model from my SAP Gateway:

```js
var oModel = new sap.ui.model.odata.ODataModel(url);
this.setModel(oModel, "model");
```

Now I have the requirement to display a property from the first line of an EntitySet.

I tried it with the following code in my XML view but without success:

```xml
<Text text="{model>/ZLLEDATSet/0/Date}" />
```

I thought the syntax should be `"modelname>/entitySet/index/PropertyName"`.

Based on the answer from @SiddP: I tried the following but I get the error

> Uncaught [object Object]

```xml
<Text text="{ 
  path: 'model>/ZLLEDATSet',
  formatter: function(value) {
    return value[0].Date;
  }
}"/>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bindProperty to Single OData Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956091/bindproperty-to-single-odata-entity)

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead.

```
       text:{ 
            path: '/ZLLEDATSet', 
            formatter: function(value){
                           return value[0].Date;
                      }
            }
```

The above code in your question just works fine. See the jsbin :http://jsbin.com/kobocidose/edit?html,js,output

If you still get error just place `alert(JSON.stringify(oModel.getData()));` to check if the data is properly set to the model.There is a good chance the your data would show null.

Comment: @alexander can you get rid of `model>` and try

Comment: What do you mean with rid?

Comment: Can you simply metion `/ZILLEDATSet` as your json path is mapped well now you just have to provide the key where you would get a value and then the value has key and value pair again where you just pick up 0th element value[0] and value of key Date from 0th element i.e. value[0].Date

Comment: My odata interface works fine. I tried it with a simple table. It works. (see code in my question)

Comment: can you create a bin so that we can check

Comment: This solution works with JsonModel. Not with an ODataModel