# Bind Association XSOData in UI5?

Tags: javascript, odata, sapui5, hana-xs

Let's say I have `Employee` entity associated with `Address` entity in XSOData and I want to bind them to a single control - `StandardListItem`. How to achieve this?

```
<List id="EmployeeList" headerText="Employees" items="{ path: '/Employee'}">
  <items>
    <StandardListItem title="{Name}" //from Employee entity
                      description="{Address/City}" //from Address entity
    />
  </items>
</List>
```

Associated address details available at `Employee('emp1')/Address/`

TIA.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SAPUI5 bindproperty to single odata entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956091/sapui5-bindproperty-to-single-odata-entity)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the `Address` element is an entity. You cannot bind a property to a whole entity. I would assume that it has some properties of its own (e.g. `Street`, `City`, etc.). You have to bind the UI5 control property to either a single property of the OData entity or use a formatter / expression binding to combine them together.

Nevertheless, you will anyway have to slightly adjust your code. The related `Address` is not retrieved by default when you do the binding as you have. To retrieve it, you should use the [$expand](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/#ExpandSystemQueryOption) option.

```
<List id="EmployeeList" headerText="Employees" 
    items="{path: '/Employee', parameters: {expand: 'Address'}}">
    <items>
        <StandardListItem title="{Name}"
                  description="{Address/SomePropertyFromTheAddressEntity}"
        />
    </items>
</List>
```