# Two bindings works by calling backend. One binding won't call backend

Tags: sapui5

Can you help me solve this mystery? I got the [walkthrough example in step 10](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/topic/8f93bf2b2b13402e9f035128ce8b495f) and adapted it so I can create a simple binding to an OData service.

Let me share the main files:

**Component.js**

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/UIComponent",
  "sap/ui/model/json/JSONModel"
], function(UIComponent, JSONModel) {
  "use strict";

  return UIComponent.extend("BasicMessages.Component", {
    metadata: {
      manifest: "json"
    },

    init: function() {
      // call the init function of the parent
      UIComponent.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
      // set data model
      var oData = {
        recipient: {
          name: "World"
        }
      };
      var oModel = new JSONModel(oData);
      this.setModel(oModel, "json");
    },

  });
});
```

**Manifest.json** (hid the service URI, but it's properly configured)

```json
{
  "_version": "1.8.0",
  "sap.app": {
    "id": "BasicMessages",
    "type": "application",
    "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
    "title": "{{appTitle}}",
    "description": "{{appDescription}}",
    "applicationVersion": {
      "version": "1.0.0"
    },
    "dataSources": {
      "mainService": {
        "uri": "hidden_service_uri",
        "type": "OData",
        "settings": {
          "odataVersion": "2.0",
          "localUri": "localService/metadata.xml"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "sap.ui": {
    "technology": "UI5",
    "deviceTypes": {
      "desktop": true,
      "tablet": true,
      "phone": true
    }
  },
  "sap.ui5": {
    "rootView": {
      "viewName": "BasicMessages.view.App",
      "type": "XML",
      "async": true,
      "id": "app"
    },
    "dependencies": {
      "minUI5Version": "1.30",
      "libs": {
        "sap.m": {}
      }
    },
    "models": {
      "i18n": {
        "type": "sap.ui.model.resource.ResourceModel",
        "settings": {
          "bundleName": "BasicMessages.i18n.i18n"
        }
      },
      "": {
        "dataSource": "mainService",
        "settings": {
          "defaultUpdateMethod": "PUT",
          "useBatch": false,
          "metadataUrlParams": {
            "sap-documentation": "heading"
          },
          "defaultBindingMode": "TwoWay"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**App.controller.js**

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/ui/core/mvc/Controller",
  "sap/m/MessageToast"
], function(Controller, MessageToast) {
  "use strict";
  
  return Controller.extend("BasicMessages.controller.App", {
    onInit: function() {
      this.getView().setModel(this.getOwnerComponent().getModel());
    },

    onShowHello: function() {
      // read msg from i18n model
      var oBundle = this.getView().getModel("i18n").getResourceBundle();
      var sRecipient = this.getView().getModel("json").getProperty("/recipient/name");
      var sMsg = oBundle.getText("helloMsg", [sRecipient]);
      // show message
      MessageToast.show(sMsg);
    },

  });
});
```

**App.view.xml (this is the tricky file)**

```xml
<mvc:View controllerName="BasicMessages.controller.App"
  xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
  xmlns="sap.m">
  <Button text="{i18n>showHelloButtonText}" press="onShowHello" />
  <Input value="{json>/recipient/name}"
    description="Hello {json>/recipient/name}"
    valueLiveUpdate="true" width="60%"
  />
  <Text text="{/Caixas(Id='0001',InicioValidade='20180712193002')/Descricao}" />
  <List items="{/Caixas}">
    <StandardListItem title="{Descricao}" />
  </List>
</mvc:View>
```

If I use the view file exactly like that, it calls the OData service on the backend and retrieve the list and the text element contents.

link to screenshot:
[image: screenshot 1]

If I comment the list lines, the OData service won't be called and the text element won't be filled with the text.

link to screenshot:
[image: screenshot 2]

Why does this happen???

Comment: Does this answer your question? [bindProperty to Single OData Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23956091/bindproperty-to-single-odata-entity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer on [SAP Docs](https://help.sap.com/viewer/0ce0b8c56fa74dd897fffda8407e8272/7.5.12/en-US/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2.html)

> Note: Requests to the back end are triggered by list bindings (ODataListBinding), element bindings (ODataContextBinding), and CRUD functions provided by the ODataModel. Property bindings (ODataPropertyBindings) do not trigger requests.

Answer (score 0):

I think, Rafael explained why this happens (your question), now to answer the unasked question "howto make this work":

You would need to bind the Text control to the entitiy and the `text` property to the `Descricio` attribute, basically something like that:

```
<Text binding="{/Caixas(Id='0001',InicioValidade='20180712193002')" text="{Descricao}" />
```

(sorry, no ui5 runtime environment at hand, so I didnt actually run this)